# Is it normal to assume equal impact time?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, collision

If we have two hammers of different weights both hitting an object with the same force can we assume they both have the same impact time?

Comment: What do you mean by "the same force?" The same maximum force during the impact? The same average force? The same impulse? or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by force you mean the average impact force of the hammer during the impact, then we have

$$F_{average}=ma_{average}=m\frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}$$

Where $\Delta t$ is the duration of the impact of the hammer and $\Delta v$ Is the change in velocity of the hammer during the impact. The product $F_{average}\Delta t$ is referred to as the impulse of force.

If each hammer stops after the impact (doesn’t bounce off the surface) then the duration of the impact will be the same if they both impact the surface with the same velocity.

Hope this helps.